# Getting contact address with membership on paypal standard

Tags: paypal

How do you get the contact created by the membership contribution screen to return the name and address (like the shipping address...) of the Paypal standard payment...

The transaction goes through properly in the sandbox (ipn ok) but contact created for the new membership has no name or address, just the email...

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have any profiles enabled on the form. You can start with the basic name and address one CiviCRM comes with out of the box or create one of your own to collect the fields you're after.

You just click on the profiles tab when managing the contribution page to enable the one(s) you'd like members to complete when they register.

Here's more information about CiviCRM profiles: http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/profiles/

Comment: Thanks for your swift answer... I would like to use the buyer's paypal information instead of having him re-enter on our form. Profiles don't seem to be mapped to the returning Paypal info. This would be similar to having the shipping address return from the transaction for a physical good...

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to do this with PayPal standard without hacking into the code. If you upgrade to PayPal Pro, you can embed the processor on the same page so everything is inputted together on once screen. This means they just complete one form and submit. Also useful if you want to collect any custom data alongside core fields like address

Comment: Thanks... Will explore further... Maybe upgrading to pro is the answer...